# preg_match 6 chars nothing else

Tags: php, preg-match, expression

Hey al just to keep it short :
i need to register some info for users via a register.php

so the username must have 6 chars atleast uppercase lowercase doen't matter. and i have to be able to put in a number or more where i want it so usernames can be like :

Stefano1
stefano321
32Stefano21
stefa1oS

Youknow?

here is what i already have and does not work :

```
if(!preg_match( "?=(?:.*?[A-Za-z]){6}", $_POST['loginName']))
{
    die("Invalid name ");
    die(header("Refresh: 5; URL=register.php"));

}
```

Comment: Have you enabled error_reporting? [What](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php) does it say?

Comment: Give up on the six character limit for usernames. Just require sensible passwords and live with the fact that some people have three letter names. If you absolutely can't, use an ([\x...-\x...]){6} range? Because there is no reason to in this day and age not support unicode.

Comment: Too bad PHP's `filter_var` has no alpha-numeric filter.

Answer (score 1):

What about this regex: `"/^[A-Za-z0-9]{6,}$/"`

Comment: will try it ASAP now using strlen so haha thanks btw!